# Pandas comparing multiindex dataframes without looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to compare two multiindex dataframes and add another column to show the difference in values (if all index value match between the first dataframe and second dataframe) without using loops

```
index_a = [1,2,2,3,3,3]
index_b = [0,0,1,0,1,2]
index_c = [1,2,2,4,4,4]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([index_a,index_b], names=('a','b'))
index_1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([index_c,index_b], names=('a','b'))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,), index=index, columns=['p'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,), index=index_1, columns=['q'])
```

df1

```
    p
a b 
1 0 .4655

2 0 .8600
  1 .9010

3 0 .0652
  1 .5686
  2 .8965
```

df2

```
    q
a b
1 0 .6591

2 0 .5684
  1 .5689

4 0 .9898
  1 .3656
  2 .6989
```

The resultant matrix (df1-df2) should look like

```
        p  diff
a b 
1 0 .4655  -0.1936 

2 0 .8600   .2916
  1 .9010   .3321   

3 0 .0652    No Match
  1 .5686    No Match
  2 .8965    No Match
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reindex_like`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex_like.html) or [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for intersection of indices:

```
df1['new'] = (df1['p'] - df2['q'].reindex_like(df1)).fillna('No Match')
#alternative
#df1['new'] = (df1['p'] - df2['q'].reindex(df1.index)).fillna('No Match')
print (df1)
            p       new
a b                    
1 0  0.955587  0.924466
2 0  0.312497 -0.310224
  1  0.306256  0.231646
3 0  0.575613  No Match
  1  0.674605  No Match
  2  0.462807  No Match
```

Another idea with [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1['new'] = (df1['p'] - df2.loc[df2.index.intersection(df1.index), 'q']).fillna('No Match')
```

Or with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
df['new'] = (df['p'] - df['q']).fillna('No Match')
print (df)
            p         q       new
a b                              
1 0  0.789693  0.665148  0.124544
2 0  0.082677  0.814190 -0.731513
  1  0.762339  0.235435  0.526905
3 0  0.727695       NaN  No Match
  1  0.903596       NaN  No Match
  2  0.315999       NaN  No Match
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following to get the difference of matached indexes. Unmatch indices will be NaN

```
diff = df1['p'] - df2['q']

#Output
a  b
1  0   -0.666542
2  0   -0.389033
   1    0.064986
3  0         NaN
   1         NaN
   2         NaN
4  0         NaN
   1         NaN
   2         NaN
dtype: float64
```